# 3 Conditional formatting rules not working together

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am using Excel 2020 and I am trying to work with three conditional formats. I am making a reference from a different sheet called "Fix Status" that is a table full of dates. With these dates, I want to find the difference from the current date (today()), once I know this I do a greater than or less than or equal with 2 conditional formatting rules for a different cell in a sheet called "Offload Status". Once the cell in the "Offload Status" sheet is filled with a date, I then want the cell to turn blue. Thus these are the three formats am trying to use and my logic with them:

1. If today's date minus the date in a specific cell is less than or equal to 2, make current cell selected green.

Condition used: `=DAYS(TODAY(),'Fix Status'!$G$2)<=2`

2. If today's date minus the date in a specific cell is greater than 2, make the current selected cell red.

Code used: `=DAYS(TODAY(),'Fix Status'!$G$2)>2`
Tower

3. If the current cell is *not* blank, make current cell selected blue.

Condition used: "Format only cells with, No Blanks"

The red and green conditions are working (1 & 2), but whenever I try to type in the cell with these conditions, the cell never turns blue (3).
I have tried changing the order in which the conditions are applied. Can someone please push me in the right direction as to why the "no blanks condition is not working? Thank you

Comment: What is the applies to range of the rules? Have you checked the Stop if true boxes?

Comment: I do not understand what these Stop is true boxes do, can you explain? and what do you mean by the range? As in, how many cells will have this?

Comment: When the condition is met it will stop processing further rules (conditions). Sometimes rules can be set up so the second one will override the first, etc. In your specific case you would want them to be cleared so it can reach the last rule to turn blue if filled in.

Answer (score 0):

If you instruct to "Format only cells with, No Blanks" then no format will be applied to blanks. If you want cells with any content to be coloured blue then the formula would be `=Len(A1)>0`

This would probably need to be the first condition and don't stop if true. The colour would then  change if one of the otehr conditions is true and, sicne that is final, evaluation should stop if one of them turns out to be True.

Comment: I'm not quite sure as to why I would need to use the len() formula. I want one cell to be based off another cell in a different sheet to turn green or red based on the date. If that one cell that is turning red or green has something inputted in the cell, then that cell will override the green or red color with a blue. That is my goal

Comment: `=Len(A1)>0` will be TRUE if the cell is blank. A1 stands for all the cells (not $A$1). You can set the range in the *Applies To* field or select all cells to which the rules apply when setting it, entering the address of the Active Cell instead of A1 in the formula.